# Cross validation after kriging, in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, interpolation, kriging, cross-validation

I performed kriging interpolation using the kriging interpolation tool in ArcToolbox, not the Geostatistical Wizard method. However, how do I determine the cross validation without using the geostatistical wizard method. In ArcToolbox, there is a cross-validation tool, but when I try to input the kriging layer I created, it doesn't allow me to.

Can I only use cross validation after creating the krig using the geostatistical wizard method?

Comment: What output do you choose for the kriging: GA layer or raster dataset? The Cross Validation tool should accept only GA layers as input.

Comment: @GISGe relate to answer above it mean that we only use cross validation for GA from Geostatistical wizard, right?